# Is html file produced by r markdown contain raw data?

Tags: r-markdown

I'm planning to use R markdown for reporting health checkup data in company. What I concern about is that if html file produced by r markdown contain the raw data (such as patient name) and accesible via that file in anyway.  If that is the case, is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without an example of your data (which I realise will be hard to share, given your question).

Basically, there's nothing in the html-version of Rmarkdown that would necessarily embed the data if you don't ask it to. If all you're planning to do is to summarise and ignore (or anonymise) individual cases then Rmarkdown should work fine.

For more information, take a look at the useful [help page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) for html pages using Rmarkdown.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I apologize for not presenting a code and a data.

I already read the help page of Rmarkdown, but wasn't sure if produced report contain personal informations.  Actually, what I planning to do is to summarise and present some graphs and summary table, so as you mentioned, I think it will work. (To make sure, I will process data to  anonymised one.)

Thank you very much. Since I can't find anyone to ask about R and Rmarkdown around me, your answer helps me a lot!